# Select2 Can't focus input box inside selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I'm trying to create a dynamic select box that has an input box for each selection, so that the user can type in the quantity.

```
function formatMaterialSelection(material) {
    return material.full_name || material.text;
}

$("#select_materials").select2({
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: "Search materials ...",
        ajax: {
                //other code here
                processResults: function(data, params) {
                            var select2data = $.map(data.materiais, function(obj) {
                                    obj.id = obj.id || obj._id;
                                    obj.full_name =
                                            `
                                  <strong><p>${obj.nome} (${obj.cod}) - ${obj.origem}</p></strong>
                                  <input class="qtd" type="number" name="${obj.id}-qtd_pedida">
                                  `
                                    obj.text = obj.text || obj.desc;
                                    return obj;
                            });
                            return {
                                    results: data.materiais,
                                    pagination: {
                                            more: (params.page * 20) < data.total_count
                                    }
                            };
                },
                //some code here
        },
        templateSelection: formatMaterialSelection
});
```

So I've got that working right now, but I can't get the user to focus on the  input inside the select2 area. Image below with what I've got:

[select2 with input number inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRTrz.png)

When I click the input box to insert the quantity it just focus back to the search area. Is there a better way to have an input box inside the selection area? Or is there a way to fix the focusing problem?

Edit: [jQuery select2. Can't get focus in the input field inside formatSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042077/jquery-select2-cant-get-focus-in-the-input-field-inside-formatselection)

I've seen this question which is the same, but the answer didn't solve it.